# How to get to HTML element of component from another component Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

here is the situation. 
Have a component(cmp1) that inside of it uses search bar component (cmp2). My goal is to dig into `cmp2` and grab `input` element to set focus on it when `cmp1` renders. How do I achieve it with `Vue`? What have I tried so far that worked was to set `ref` on `cmp2`, than through `this.$refs.search.$el.firstChild[0].focus()` but I realize that this is not an option. So, perhaps you'd help me out with this one. some screenshots attached. Many thanks! [image: cmp1]
[image: cmp-2 search component I need to dig in to]

Comment: If cmp1 parent component of cmp2 so why should  you do this in cmp1?just focus input in `mounted` hook in cmp2

Comment: thanks, although cmp2 is also used elsewhere, where there is no need for focus on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create method in `search-payment-component` and ref `input` element:

   ```
   methods: {
       ...
       focus() { this.$refs.input.focus() }
       ...
   }
   ```

   And call this method in parent component with `this.$refs.searchComponent.focus()` (yes, you should also ref child component to use it).
2. Add prop `focused` to `search-payment-component`:

   ```
   props: ['focused'],
   ...
   watch: {
       focused(val) { val && this.$refs.input.focus() }
   }
   ```

   But you should also provide events when focus is lost as best practice.

[UPDATED]
OR
if you want just focus input on initial rendering:

```
    props: { focused: Boolean },
    ...
    mounted() {
        focused && this.$refs.input.focus();
    }

    // in parent template
    ...
    // if you just declared attribute(w/o value) it will be true 
    <search-payment-component focused ><search-payment-component>
    ...
```

Also if you want to work with child component in `mounted` hook you should use it in `this.$nextTick` method to be sure that child component was rendered.

Comment: Thanks Max, this should do the trick, could you elaborate on step 2 please? Why do we watch a prop? and what do I pass from parent as `focused`?  Thank you

Comment: if you want just focus input on rendering so I updated answer for this and watcher is not needed more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually set these by accessing the child html elements.

If I understand correctly, you want to execute a function of the child triggered by the parent.

1. One way to do that is to have the parent have a `loaded` state default to false. Pass the state as a prop to the child, and then you can add a watch for this state to the child. When the loaded changes to true, your watch should trigger the desired action.
2. You can complicate things a bit by having an emit in the child pass a function or the input to the parent that you can manage from there.

But as mentioned in the comment, this doesn't need to be a complicated rective situation. I think  what may suffice is having a `isFocused` prop available to the parent.

---

example for #1:

in parent:

```
<template>
  <my-component :isFocused="focusedElement === 'item-1'"/>
</template>

<script>
  data () {
    focusedElement: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.focusedElement = 'item-1'
  }
</script>
```

in child/component:

```
<script>
  params: ['isFocused'],
  watch: {
    isFocused(val){
      if (val === true) {
        this.$refs.input.focus() 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

example for #2:

to emit a function, you could do this in the child

```
  methods: {
    setFocus() { this.$refs.input.focus() }
  }
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('onMounted', this.setFocus);
  },
```

then, in the parent you would use the `@onMounted` listener to register the function. you would still need to store the function and manage when the function fires from the parent. I think option one is a better choice

Comment: Thanks Daniel! What do I need to emit from child to be able to set `focus` and maybe `tabindex` on child's input field inside parent? Cheers